# Change page and reload

Tags: javascript

I have an onClick function:

```
onclick="return confirmDelete() && document.location.reload();"
```

which successfully runs my confirmDelete function and refreshes the page where the confirm happened.

I want to go ahead one page using history.go(1) and then reload the page brought up by the call to history. I have tried

```
document.location.reload(history.go(1));
```

but it didn't work. Is it possible to go to the next page and reload that page? I can successfully run document.location.reload() and history.go(1), but not together. I even tried

```
onclick="return confirmDelete() && history.go(1) && document.location.reload();"
```

without success.

Comment: No; that is not possible.

Comment: You went back to the previous page; your code is longer accessible from there (or at least, it shouldn't).

Comment: why not just send the user back to the previous page and don't even muddle with the history.go() business.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use HTML5's `history.pushState` and `popState` to achieve something similar, like pushing a state in your `confirmDelete` and then listening for `popstate` events in your pages to check if a state was pushed.

Not sure if it's exactly what you're after or if it's going to work, but [here](http://html5doctor.com/history-api/) is some further detail on the history API.

Answer (score 0):

Oh yeah since we are using javascript anyway, use cookies. Just before going to the previous page set a cookie -- And on page load if your cookie is set remove cookie, refresh!

Comment: I'm pretty new to Javascript. How would I do that?

Comment: check [this out](http://forrst.com/posts/cookie_js_a_JavaScript_cookie_library-VZX) maybe?